# Mongoexport or Mongodump in large collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongoexport

When I do a mongodump on the existing collection the dump stops on 23% of the dump. The file is about 1.2 GB.
I tried also mongoexport.  But this also stops at 23%.
The dump/export always stops at 21257107 records.
It this normal?
(OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

```
mongodump -h localhost:27020 -d SensorData -c Values -o Dump
connected to: localhost:27020
2016-02-15T09:41:25.099+0100 DATABASE: SensorData to Dump/SensorData
2016-02-15T09:41:25.101+0100    SensorData.Values to Dump/SensorData/Values.bson
2016-02-15T09:41:28.178+0100            Collection File Writing Progress: 434100/91183458       0%      (documents)
2016-02-15T09:41:31.051+0100            Collection File Writing Progress: 940300/91183458       1%      (documents)
-------------------
2016-02-15T09:47:34.002+0100            Collection File Writing Progress: 21155100/91183458     23%     (documents)
2016-02-15T09:47:37.339+0100             21257107 documents
2016-02-15T09:47:37.339+0100    Metadata for SensorData.Values to Dump/SensorData/Values.metadata.json

mongoexport -host localhost:27020 --db SensorData --collection Values -vv  --out filename.json
2016-02-15T10:51:33.507+0100 creating new connection to:localhost:27020
2016-02-15T10:51:33.507+0100 [ConnectBG] BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
2016-02-15T10:51:33.508+0100 connected to server localhost:27020 (127.0.0.1)
2016-02-15T10:51:33.508+0100 connected connection!
connected to: localhost:27020
exported 21257107 records
```

Comment: No, not at all. Check available disk space etc.

Comment: Disk space is no problem.